# Display none Image Overlay

Tags: react-leaflet

Is there any way I can include a display: none within the style of the module

`<ImageOverlay url = {url} bounds = {[[-56, -100], [12.52, - 25.24]]}/>`

Comment: Just wrap it with a flag and make it true or false depending on when you want to be visible `{yourFlag && <ImageOverlay.../>`